# cakephp 2.1 how to upload an image in a simple form and viewing it

Tags: image, cakephp, upload

Its so crazy how something so simple can be so difficult.

Please calling all cakephp 2.1 gurus. I have a form, it has a name and text image (var) field.

I would like to simply post an image, no resizing, no thumbnail, not anything special, just a simple mvc example of posting up an image and viewing it in the view.ctp.

Thats it. I have gone through the /en/2.1 book and api on cakephp.org but I just can't seem to get the mvc working as far as seeing it upload into a folder and viewing it in ctp.

My controller

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->ListShExPainImage->create();
        if ($this->ListShExPainImage->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The list sh ex pain image has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The list sh ex pain image could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}

public function view($id = null) {
    $this->ListShExPainImage->id = $id;
    if (!$this->ListShExPainImage->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid list sh ex pain image'));
    }
    $this->set('listShExPainImage', $this->ListShExPainImage->read(null, $id));
}
```

My add.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ListShExPainImage');?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add List Sh Ex Pain Image'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('name');
    echo $this->Form->input('image', array('type' => 'file'));
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>
```

My view.ctp

```
<h2><?php  echo __('List Sh Ex Pain Image');?></h2>
<dl>
    <dt><?php echo __('Id'); ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <?php echo h($listShExPainImage['ListShExPainImage']['id']); ?>
        &nbsp;
    </dd>
    <dt><?php echo __('Name'); ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <?php echo h($listShExPainImage['ListShExPainImage']['name']); ?>
        &nbsp;
    </dd>
    <dt><?php echo __('Image'); ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <?php echo h($listShExPainImage['ListShExPainImage']['image']); ?>
        &nbsp;
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated, thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you're not doing **anything** with the file upload. Even though Cake works magic sometimes, automagically guessing what you want to do with that upload is not one of them.

As stated in [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3afile), the file upload field returns a data array with several keys. You should take the `name` key and save it as the `image` field (as that's what you seem to be calling). For example:

```
$filename = $this->request->data['ListShExPainImage']['image']['name'];

// Move the image
move_uploaded_file(
    $this->request->data['ListShExPainImage']['image']['tmp_name'],
    '/path/to/your/image/dir/' . basename($filename)'
);

// Set the filename in the database
$this->request->data['ListShExPainImage']['image'] = $filename;
```

Furthermore, you'll need to have a so called `multipart/form-data` enctype set to your form in order to be able to parse image uploads, by adding the file type to the [Form create options](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create).

And also, don't forget to move the file from your temp folder to a final location.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I copied and pasted some images to test the view. I did this to test to see if the view was working as advised by the answer given below. I have tried both answers and it just does not want to physically upload the images into the folder. I created a folder img_list_sh_ex in my webroot. What am I missing. I'm working in wamp / windows 7. Any clues. Could it be the premissions on the folder? Being a virtual server I wouldnt thing that this was the case?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add a 'type' to your form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('ListShExPainImage', array('type' => 'file'));?>
```

Then in the Controller do something like this:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($data['ListShExPainImage']['image']['tmp_name']))
{
    move_uploaded_file(
        $this->request->data['ListShExPainImage']['image']['tmp_name'],
        '/path/to/your/image/dir/' . $this->request->data['ListShExPainImage']['image']['name']
    );

    // store the filename in the array to be saved to the db
    $this->request->data['ListShExPainImage']['image'] = $this->request->data['ListShExPainImage']['image']['name'];
}
```

Then do your create and save routine.

In your View you would do someting like this to show the image:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('/path/to/your/image/dir/' . $listShExPainImage['ListShExPainImage']['image']); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Both posts were really helpful in showing me what all must be done. Your view.ctp was just so so helpful. As I have commented in the above post. I just cannot get an image to upload to a folder. I have copied and pasted a few images into an img_list_sh_ex folder in my webroot just to test the view.ctp but for some or other reason its just not uploading images. Cake also returns no errors as well. Could it be permissions? I'm using wamp / windows 7.

Comment: Chances are very good it is permission related, but I am sorry I can't help much on Windows.